# Dismiss ViewController that is presented via Popup

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, popup, uipopovercontroller

So i am creating an ipad recipe based app using storyboards. Just to give you an idea of the structure of my program here is the flow of View controllers:

> ViewController --Modally--> PreviewViewController --Modally-->
>   RecipeViewController --Popup--> IngredientsViewController

All of this has been done in storyboarding. I created the `IngredientsViewController` and have linked it up to the `RecipeViewController` to be displayed as a popup, which works fine. However i want to be able to dismiss the `IngredientsViewController` programatically (because i've implemented voice command features). The problem is i can't seem to access the `IngredientsViewController` to dismiss it. (appologies i can't yet post any pictures).

I am using the following code to present the `IngredientsViewController` programatically (from within `RecipeViewController`):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ingr" sender:nil];
```

Which works fine to display the popup, but i cant dismiss it. I've tried to access it through the hierarchy of view controllers but cannot seem to find it, i would assume that it would be at the top of the stack, but apparently not? I've tried things like:

```
[self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Again this was called from within `RecipeViewController`. But that simply dismisses the `RecipeViewController` and not the `IngredientsViewController` that is being presented by popup.

Just to be clear the `IngredientsViewController` is not a `UIPopoverController`, it is a normal `viewController` created in storyboard, and its segue style is popup linked to a button in the `RecipeViewController`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any button in `IngredientsViewController` to dismiss?

Comment: No i want to dismiss it from within the RecipeViewController, I use the voice control stuff to dismiss it (but none of that is the problem its just the actual method to dismiss it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIPopoverController *popOver = (UIPopoverController *)self.presentedViewController;
[popOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

This should do the trick if your destination view controller is a `UIPopoverController`

Comment: My destination ViewController is not a UIPopoverController, its a normal viewController, but thanks i might look into making it a UIPopoverController.

Comment: I decided to make it a UIPopoverController in the end then just instantiate the ViewController in the popover. So it was simple to present it and dismiss it from within the same ViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `presentViewController:animated:completion:` instead of `performSegueWithIdentifier:`?

Comment: I just tried this method using the following code: `UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

            UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IngrCtr"];

            [self presentViewController: vc animated:YES completion:nil];`

It sort of worked, but instead of presenting it as a popover of my defined size, it just presents it as a full screen covering over my previous view controller.

Comment: i realised why i used performSegueWithIdentifier, its because i pass it information through that segue, so i need to stick to presenting it in that method, or find another way of passing it information.